# Link of zero set of a quasi homogeneous polynomial in $\Bbb C[x,y,z]$ has a Seifert fibered structure

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

I have a question about Seifert fibered 3-manifold while reading this survey paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602562.pdf.

In Example 22 (p.10), it is said that for integers $a,b,c\geq 1$, set $S_{abc}:=(x^ay+y^bz+z^cx)\subset \Bbb C^3$. $S_{abc}$ is quasihomogeneous with weights $(bc-c+1,ca-a+1,ab-b+1)$, thus its link is a Seifert fibered 3-manifold $L_{abc}\to S^2$ with 3 multiple fibers of multiplicities $ab-b+1,bc-c+1,ca-a+1$.

I can see that $S_{abc}$ is quasihomogeneous with weights $(bc-c+1,ca-a+1,ab-b+1)$, but how does this imply that the $L_{abc}$ has a Seifert fibered structure? How is $L_{abc}\to S^2$ defined? And how do we know that it has 3 multiple fibers of multiplicities $ab-b+1,bc-c+1,ca-a+1$?

Comment: On such a link you get a *pseudofree* circle action, i.e. an action which is free on a complement to a finite set of orbits.   Such actions imply Seifert manifold structure with the Seifert fibration given by the orbits. Consider reading, say, Orlik's book "Seifert manifolds."